# Proof $\vert{\frac{1}{z^2 -1}}\vert\le \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

For everything z in the circle {$z \in \Bbb C : z=2e^{i\theta} $}

Comment: Proof $\vert{\frac{1}{z^2 -1}}\vert\le \frac{1}{3}$ 
This, I am new

Comment: You should let us know where you have difficulties. What have you tried? Are you stuck on some concept? Is your calculation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z^2-1|^2 = (4\cos(2\theta)-1)^2+16\sin^2(2\theta) = 16-8\cos(2\theta)+1=17-8\cos(2\theta) \geq 9$.

Hence $\frac{1}{|z^2-1|} \leq 3$

Comment: $\sqrt{16\cos(2\theta)^2-8\cos(2\theta)+1+16\sin(2\theta)^2}=\sqrt{2-8\cos(2\theta)}$

I was wrong in the trigonometric identity
I wrote 1 instead of 16.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma=\{z:z=2e^{i\theta}\}$ and let $z \in \gamma$. Note that $\gamma$ is the circle radius $2$. Now for these problems it is often easier to work backwards from the solution to figure out what steps to take. So lets do this. Start with 
$$ |\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}|\leq \frac{1}{3} $$ Getting rid of the denominators gives us 
$$3 \leq |z^{2}-1|$$
Adding $1$ to both sides and using some triangle inequality  gives us 
$$ 4 \leq |z^{2}-1|+1 \leq |z|^{2}+|1|+1= |z|^{2}+2 $$
Hence $4 \leq |z|^{2}$ meaning $2 \leq |z|$. Note that $|z|=2$ satisfies this condition. Try for yourself to see if you can do these steps backwards. Let me know if you need more help